# How to import css files in vue 3 child components?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I'm working on *Vue 3*, and I need to know how I can import different style sheets for different child components.

For example, I have 3 child components, let's say `A` and `B`, and I want to import style sheet `X` in `A` and style sheet `Z` in `B`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Importing CSS in Vue components**

If you are setup and using webpack, you should be able to import css directly from inside `<style>` tags in component files.

```
// In Component A
<style scoped>
@import "./X.css"
</style>

// In Component B
<style scoped>
@import "./Y.css"
</style>
```

More info here:

- https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html
- https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would also like to add that it can be imported like this 
// In Component A
<script scoped>
import '@/assets/user/css/userapp.css'
</script>

Comment: Ah yes, i appologise, you mentioned you have vue-cli, this sets up the webpack alias "@" for you :P